# convert in to int to string

Tags: javascript, node.js

/*  In java-script while i converting the float to string for spiting the values. while converting it removes the last zeros after the dot. but i calculates the numbers not accecpting the zeros how to overcome this i have give in example 2.*/

```
//(Eg : 1)
    var num=2.15;
    var res=0;
    var str=num.toString();
    console.log("str",str);
    var numarray=str.split('.');
    var a=new Array();
    a=numarray;
    console.log(a[0]);
    console.log(a[1]);

/* OUTPUT :
 str => 2.15 ----> (Its bring the value)
 a[0] => 2
 a[1] => 15 */

//(Eg :2)
    var num=2.10;
    var res=0,a1,b1;
    var str=num.toString();
    console.log("str",str);
    var numarray=str.split('.');
    var a=new Array();
    a=numarray;
    console.log(a[0]);
    console.log(a[1]);

/* OUTPUT :
 str => 2.1  ---> (In that zero is not considering how to convert it )
 a[0] => 2
 a[1] => 1  -----> (I need whole value 10) */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of numarray second item, if length is less than 2 means that it needs to concatenate a zero, try this:

```js
var num = 2.10;
var res = 0, a1, b1;
var str = num.toString();
    
var numarray = str.split('.');
a = numarray;

console.log(a[0]);
console.log(a[1].length < 2 ? a[1] + '0' : a[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know that you need to decimal places, you can do this.

```js
var num=2.10;
var str = num.toFixed(2);
var arr = str.split('.');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: But when the user enter the num value (num=2.1) it will automatically add zero at last. need to both cases @D. Seah